# VSCODE: Flutter failing to build for Android

Tags: flutter

```
    flutter  run      
Launching lib/main.dart on AC2001 in debug mode...
Checking the license for package SDK Patch Applier v4 in /home/diva/Android/Sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package SDK Patch Applier v4 not accepted.         
Checking the license for package Android Emulator in /home/diva/Android/Sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android Emulator not accepted.             
Checking the license for package Android SDK Tools in /home/diva/Android/Sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Tools not accepted.            
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 in /home/diva/Android/Sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 30 in /home/diva/Android/Sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 30 not accepted.      
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     patcher;v4 SDK Patch Applier v4                                    
     platforms;android-30 Android SDK Platform 30                       
     emulator Android Emulator                                          
     tools Android SDK Tools                                            
     build-tools;29.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2                  
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
                                                                        
  Using Android SDK: /home/diva/Android/Sdk                             
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 1s                                                      
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                      2,203ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I am trying to run Flutter using VSCODE and haven't downloaded Android Studio. I have just started learning Flutter, so pretty new.

Android SDK build Tool == 29.0.3
and Flutter ==  2.2.3

NEW: After running flutter doctor, It said I should run for android-licenses

```
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/diva/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at:
      /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin/java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
      18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to
      accept the SDK licenses.
      See
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/
      linux#android-setup for more details.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome
```

flutter doctor --android-licenses

```
Android sdkmanager tool not found
(/home/diva/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#
android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

Comment: run `flutter doctor` then post the output

Answer (score 0):

> run this 'flutter doctor --android-licenses' then enter y for accepting each
> licenses. the CMD will show you each license one by one which you have
> to accept by entering y in CMD prompt. It solved my problem. I hope
> this will also work for you

Answer (score 0):

As the error output is suggesting. You need to accept license agreements

> Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.

to solve this

1. go to your terminal
2. flutter doctor --android-licenses
3. press (y) to

   accept